# Webscraping code for clicking on a button stopped working

Tags: python, selenium

I am not great at webscraping pages, but I had managed (with some support) to develop a code that would visit a specific website, look for a company name and click on the view button to see what violations the company had incurred into and scrape the data out of it. Now, the code stops working when I try to click on the 'View' button and I am not sure why.

Here is my code, can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

```
matched_suppliers = ['bac giang lng garment corporation']


length =  len(matched_suppliers)

aggregator = []

for idx, i in enumerate(matched_suppliers):
    rem = length-idx
    print('This is index: ', idx, ', element: ', i, ', with remaining : ', rem, ' elements')
    try:
        print(i, )
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get('https://portal.betterwork.org/transparency/compliance')
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.ID, "loader-wrapper")))
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.k-loading-mask")))
        input_text = i
        driver.find_element_by_id("pnlHdAdvanceSearch").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("txtSearchFactory").send_keys(input_text)
        driver.find_element_by_id("btnSearchData").click()
        view_button = "//tr[contains(.,'{}')]/td/a"
        time.sleep(3)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, view_button.format(input_text)))).click()
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "window01"))).click()
        time.sleep(5)
        issue = driver.find_element_by_id('gridInfoList').text
        print(issue)
        aggregator.append([i, issue])
        driver.quit()
    except:
        pass

bw_issues = pd.DataFrame(aggregator, columns=['Factory', 'Reason'])
bw_issues
```

Comment: Please update (if any) error traces so that it makes it easy to debug the problem.

Comment: From a quick glance, what you trying to do here `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, view_button.format(input_text)))).click()` is to click an element with the text, e.g. `bac ` . But the way your `xpath` is setup it can resolve to more than one element that contains the word e.g. `bac` in which case it will not be able to make the click due to multiple elements. And am i correct that you want to click the `view` button of the first row which contains the keyword?

Comment: yes! I want to click on the view button for the company selected. Clicking on the view button a tiny window opens with some key info that I want to scrape. How can I do it?